# Can a spell deal non-lethal damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

So the rules, to my knowledge, say that a melee attack can be non-lethal. Does this mean that a spell like Inflict Wounds or Primal Savagery can be non-lethal? As for ranged spells, I imagine a volatile spell like *Fireball* or *Lightning Bolt* that can hit multiple enemies couldn't be restrained to non-lethal, but what about a single target spell like *Chromatic Orb* or *Eldritch Blast*?

Comment: Despite my opening of this question as a duplicate, I feel the answers in the other question are incomplete (compared to Rubiksmoose's answer here)

Comment: @L0neGamer I agree, but the correct solution in the SE system to insufficient answers is to improve or add to the answers using a variety of systems we have in place. (I didn't realize it was a duplicate when I answered). As such I have put an answer on the original question as well. If it is determined to be better or more correct than the current ones, voting will eventually sort it out.

Answer (score 8):

## Only spells that include a melee attack

First, a note:  there is no such thing as "non-lethal damage" in 5e. Instead there is a rule called "knocking a creature out" which is the only way to do damage without killing a creature that the rules provide.

> Sometimes an attacker wants to incapacitate a foe, rather than deal a killing blow. When an attacker reduces a creature to 0 hit points with a **melee attack**, the attacker can knock a creature out. The attacker can make this choice the instant that damage is dealt. The creature falls unconscious and is stable.

Melee attack is a general category including melee weapon attacks as well as melee spell attacks. If a spell includes a melee spell attack, you can choose to apply this rule.

For example, the spell *steel wind strike* says:

> Make a melee spell attack against each target.

Thus, you could apply the rule for knocking a creature out to those attacks. Also worth noting that this spell affects multiple targets. That doesn't matter; as long as it does melee attacks you  can choose to knock them out.